# Make turtles respect a diagonal obstacle

Tags: netlogo

I can't figure out how to design an obstacle that is a diagonal line. Imagine a door at the corner of a room, the walls would be the obstacles. My turtles move forward by following a rule of cone vision and making a decision if there are people forward. But as shapes in NetLogo are drawings I'm unable to tell the turtle to look if there is an obstacle ahead.

Making it simple, my turtles move this way

```
let people-ahead min-one-of other people in-cone distance angle [distance myself]    
ifelse people-ahead = nobody [speed-up] [speed-down]
```

I'm looking for an idea to achieve people respect an obstacle (walls - the door at the corner of the room ) the door is 3 patches wide and its heading es 180

Comment: Is it sufficient to have your turtles avoid the entire patch where the obstacle occurs, or are you wanting the turtle to avoid narrow walls but still be able to step onto the patch? How are you defining an obstacle - for example, do you colour the patch, or have a list somewhere that stores the position of obstacles?

Comment: The thing is that the obstacle should be a diagonal line that can't be made of patches because of its heading. Imagine points are people and / are obstacles it should look like this. /...\ . I am trying to make little obstacles / in a line and ask the turtles if they can see then in cone vision

Comment: If you don't want to make up the obstacle with patches, then you have to make it up with turtles. You can create a breed called 'obstacles' (or whatever) and lay them down wherever you want. Then use the code you have already, but detect obstacles instead of people.